# UIBarButtonItem's TintColor incorrectly grey on iPhone 5C, but correctly white on 4S, 6, and all Simulator options. Why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationbar

[image]

The top Nav Bar seen in the image attached is what I see on my iPhone 4S, my iPhone 6, and all instances of the Simulator (4S, 5, 5S, 6, 6+).

However, when I run on my iPhone 5C, I get the bottom Nav Bar seen in the image attached. The top left BarButtonItem is a custom image. The top right is the default "Add" button.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your iphone/ipad settings General > Accessibility > Increase Contrast > Darken Colors = OFF